# All view controllers on a single storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, xcode9, xcode-storyboard

Back to XCode 5 and 6 times, putting all view controllers on to one single storyboard was not recommended, and my experience proved it: XCode became slow.

What is the situation today? Can XCode 9 handle this? Does Apple officially recommend to put everything into one singular storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to divide app in modules or something like "flows"; for example I usually create the **Onboarding** storyboard that contains login/registration stuff, or **Settings** storyboard that contains settings menu and submenu (which are all view controllers).
Furthermore, I never create **UITableViewCell** or **UICollectionViewCell** in directly in storyboard, but I create a dedicated **.xib** file.
I use the same @Prashant Tukadiya methods to handle View controller instantiation and storyboard handling (in a more generic way).

> What is the situation today? Can XCode 9 handle this?

I worked on a project 1-2 years ago that contains all view controllers in a single storyboard, I recently opened it in XCode 9 and it's still a extremely slow.

Answer (score 1):

As you like , sometimes you have to do this when number of view controllers in main storyboards increases also to divide app features when you app becomes larger and storyboard opens/saves slowly

Answer (score 1):

You should divide your storyboard in module wise. otherwise your project will take much time in a single change in storyboard.

My suggesion is 
you can use Storyboard Reference to connect via segue see example

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards

and if you don't want segue a better solution is have abstract method practice in your every viewcontroller to access from storyboard

Just like

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// MARK: - Abstract Methods

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class func viewController () -> LoginVC {
    return StoryBoard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.controller.LoginVC) as! LoginVC
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Now access it with  LoginVC.viewController() and do push or present whatever your operation you requred
```

I manage everything in constant file

```
public struct StoryBoard {

static let main = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

       struct controller {
           static let LoginVC   =   "LoginView"

         }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I create different storyboards for divided logical units and pass references to them (Storyboard reference in XCode). It helps to keep them more organized. Also there is a nice library named R.swift on GitHub (see https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift) such as file with resources in Android. It parses all resources such as images, nibs, storyboards etc. and reduces possibilities of making mistakes when calling resources by name.